# Spring framework structure

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to understand the spring framework architecture (learning to use spring as well), and setup the framework source in eclipse. Can anyone point to where the bootstrap of the framework occurs if I refer spring core in my application. I see the core package, but not sure where to look for. A brief note on how the framework is initialized would be highly helpful.
thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to add more info on how you are using Spring and what, specifically, you are looking for that you can't just find in the debugger, e.g.

Comment: thanks daventron, I am trying to learn how the framework itself work. So, how it bootstraps, major architectural components.. It is more of a learning on how to implement a framework itself. It would be a help if i get a head start, at least where the flow starts. thanks.

Comment: The manual (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/) is helpful and comprehensive. If you have specific questions after reading the basics there, then you'll get a more helpful response.

Answer (score 3):

The first JAR in Spring is spring-core, but it doesn't do anything special from programmer's point of view. The first really important JAR is spring-beans (which also uses spring-core). And one of most important classes in spring-beans is XMLBeanFactory - using it you bootstrap Spring in any, even a small desktop application.
On this JAR depend other, more complex: spring-context, spring-web, etc...

You can always see what depends on what with Maven, and if you don't have Maven, you can use eg mvnrepository.com: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans/3.0.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are talking about a Springified webapp, its `/WEB-INF/web.xml` file will typically contain servlet declarations like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

The `DispatcherServlet` will cause the framework to initialize, triggered (I think) by the servlet initialization event.

There are other ways too ...

Comment: thank you... that really helps.. I would trace from there.. also, what is the triggering point for a standalone application where spring is used as basic DI container.. thanks again

Comment: As I wrote in my answer: for standalone applications is XMLBeanFactory (or ClassPathXMLApplicationContext - which however does many things, most of which are unnecessary for standalone applications)